# ComboBox header content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ComboBox` defined in `XAML, WPF`.

I would like to set in the header a picture.

As defined - the header of the `ComboBox` includes the selected item.

How can I change it to show a picture and enable it to be changed to a different one while pressing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to modify the template of your combobox to a new one.

Here is a good [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean that you want to make the items in the comboBox images instead of texts? if yes, this is the answer:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Margin="166,32,173,348">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
            <ComboBoxItem.Content>
                <Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Unpassed.png" />
            </ComboBoxItem.Content>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem.Content>
                <Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/passed.png" />
            </ComboBoxItem.Content>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

[image]